# Graph API: Where comments went?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have been successfully using Graph API for months but something happened.

Normally I used PHP and json to parse graph api results.

```
json(https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=$searchterm&type=post&locale=$ch&$key)
```

But now it seems that comments section has disappeared from public posts.

So now I have to search comments separately with /post_ID/comment, and it's really slow because there can be lots of posts (and comments from posts are really rare in this way).

Is there anyway faster way or somehow enable "old" way with permissions or..?

I suppose that there has been some heavy alterations with graph api or facebook privacy options...

Answer (score 0):

The `comments` field in the Post Graph object ([reference here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)) requires the `read_stream` extended permission.  Search of public posts does not return the `comments` field now.

Not totally clear on what answer you are looking for, but if a confirmation, then, yes, you are correct...comments are not returned via public post search results.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was looking for.

Well have to think something, old way was better and more efficient. Why comments section had to be removed from public posts. :/

I think the situation was the same before summer but then comments came back to stream and now they are again removed.

Comment: Ok, if you think my answer is correct, I'd appreciate you marking it so. Thanks!